# Implementing IPC using Binder from C/C++

Tags: android, ipc, native-activity

I have an Android App that is fully written in C.  I'd like to be able to implement IPC natively, i.e. - not come back up to Java via JNI if possible.

I have read that since the Binder APIs are not part of the NDK APIs, I should not use it directly from my C code and instead rely on the Java APIs using JNI.  Since its not supported, the API may change and probably has over the past few versions.

My question is - Can I use Binder directly from C/C++ and is it still considered good practice?  And, also, would I run into any security problems doing so?